# ubuntu preseed, An error occurred while creating the keyfile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, installation

i am trying to encrypt my hard disk(full hard disk encryption) while ubuntu install.
i am trying to automate it using preseed file.
my preseed file is

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password helloworld
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password helloworld
```

but when preseed run it show me the error.
An error occurred while creating the keyfile.
i am unable to debug it